# Map is blinking frequently

Tags: javascript, meteor, mapbox, meteor-blaze, mapbox-gl-js

I am using Mapbox GL JS with a meteor+blaze application. When the user drags the map it starts blinking and sometimes it blinks even without dragging the map.

I have used meteor.autorun to insert the dynamic marker into map based on category selection.

Please guide me, how I can fix it.

Comment: Can you show what you've tried?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please make sure you read the [help for asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), in particular about providing an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you may be describing https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/5490, a GPU-specific bug that was patched in the most recent release (v0.42.1). Does your issue persist if you upgrade to that version?